# NullPointerException on ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I've been trying to populate my empty `HorizontalScrollView` with `ImageView`s programmatically created ('cause I don't know how many they are going to be; gotta fetch JSON data from the web to find out). Also, I have to set the displayed image of the `ImageView`s using Fedor Vlasov's LazyList ('cause I'm loading it from a link). I have the following code:

```
private void displayListOfPlants() {
    HorizontalScrollView scrollVPlants = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollVPlants);
    for (int i = 0; i < mPlantList.size(); i++) {
        ImageView imgVPlant = new ImageView(CropRotationPlannerActivity.this);
        scrollVPlants.addView(imgVPlant);
        MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(mPlantList.get(i).get(InfoBookActivity.TAG_IMAGE_LOCATION), imgVPlant);
    }
}
```

This method is called on my `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method. And I call my `AsyncTask`'s `execute()` method in my Activity's `onResume()` method.

However, when I run the code, I get the following errors:

```
08-20 04:43:38.253    2727-2727/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb, PID: 2727
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.fedorvlasov.lazylist.ImageLoader.DisplayImage(java.lang.String, android.widget.ImageView)' on a null object reference
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity.displayListOfPlants(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:146)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity.access$100(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:28)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity$LoadPlants.onPostExecute(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:166)
        at thesleeplesselite.drgreenthumb.CropRotationPlannerActivity$LoadPlants.onPostExecute(CropRotationPlannerActivity.java:150)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

At this point, I have no idea what to do. I have no idea why my `ImageView`s are null.

**EDIT:**

*I've modified my code to the following and it now works properly*:

```
private void displayListOfPlants() {
    LinearLayout linearLayoutForPlants = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForPlants);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParamsForPlants = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20,20);
    for (int i = 0; i < mPlantList.size(); i++) {
        ImageView imgVPlant = new ImageView(CropRotationPlannerActivity.this);
        imgVPlant.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParamsForPlants);
        linearLayoutForPlants.addView(imgVPlant);
        MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(mPlantList.get(i).get(InfoBookActivity.TAG_IMAGE_LOCATION), imgVPlant);
    }
}
```

So, yeah. For newbies out there just like me. Note of that:
(1) You can't add an `ImageView` directly to a `ScrollView`
(2) Make sure to add a `LayoutParams`
(3) Make sure everything is properly initialized.

NOTE: I stored my JSON tags in my `InfoBookActivity.java` as static strings, so I don't have to create ones like those every single time.

And I made an ImageLoader object in my `MainActivity.java` so as for overall use in the app.

Comment: `ImageView imgVPlant = new ImageView(CropRotationPlannerActivity.this);` are you sure this and `MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(mPlantList.get(i).get(InfoBookActivity.TAG_IMAGE_LOCATION), imgVPlant);` this is not null?

Comment: MainActivity.imageLoader.DisplayImage(mPlantList.get(i).get(InfoBookActivity.TAG_IMAGE_LOCATION), imgVPlant);
This will surely be null

Comment: I ought to check again. Will reply later.

Comment: The `imageLoader` isn't null. I've used this in my other activities. It's really the `ImageView` and I'm still confused on how to not make it `null`.

Comment: Ok. I take that back. Both of you are right. My `imageLoader` is `null`. The weird thing is, I've used it like in two other activities and this exception has never popped up. So sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i have facing same error(null object reference for imageLoader) in my code, when i try to call the imageLoader.DisplayImage() for viewing the images in ImageView i got the same error. Right now i have found the solution for this error.

Please initialize the imageLoader with the current activity, use the following code:

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
```

here "this" is the object of the current activity, 
now you call the DisplayImage() after this code

I hope this code will help you

Answer (score 0):

You cant add `Imagviews` to `Scrollview` directly you have to add linearlayout to it and then add `imageviews` to that `linearlayout`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've modified my code accordingly. But still, I am getting the NullPointerException. I'm beginning to think the problem lies in the declaration and initialization of the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you created **ImageView** but you failed to add **params** to imageView.And also you add the imageView directly to ScrollView.Add Linear Layout to ScrollView and then add ImageView to LinearLayout.I think thats why you are getting **null pointer exception**.First add params to your imageView and try again.

Comment: I updated my code. Still, I get the NullPointerException.

Comment: are you sure this LinearLayout  id R.id.linearLayoutForPlants exists in your layout i mean inside Horizontalscrollview

Comment: Yup. I added it on my xml file for this activity.

Comment: declare this line within oncreate LinearLayout linearLayoutForPlants = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForPlants);

Comment: I thank you really for trying to help and pointing out about the `LayoutParams` thing. I have found out the problem. My `imageLoader` was the culprit. I've never thought so because I've used it twice like that in other classes and no error ever pops out.